How to forward the arguments of a constructor to a function in OCaml?
I have a type with constructors which take many arguments. When pattern matching on a constructor of this type, I would like to forward the arguments as a pack (maybe a tuple?), without having to retype them all.
This is code I would like to write:
type foo_t =
  | FromInt of int * int
  | FromFloat of float

let sum_pair (a, b) =
  a + b
;;

let f foo =
  match foo with
  | FromInt (a, b) as pair -> sum_pair pair
  | FromFloat _ -> 0
;;


The problem here is that pair is typed as foo_t instead of int * int. But sum_pair should expect a pair of ints and not a foo_t.

It seems that there it's not possible to do what I'm asking (for good or bad reasons). Should I accept an answer that says it's impossible?

As others have said FromInt (a, b) isn't a tuple. Internally it's a box with a tag and 2 values. I wonder if you could make FromInt of int * int an unboxed tuple in some way that lets you make it type compatible with un-tagged tuples. But it probably won't work and you would need Obj.magic to make the type system not throw a fit.

I think there are a pair of misconceptions about how OCaml works at play here.
The simplest is that as binds a name just to the thing immediately to the left. Rather, it is greedy. It binds a name to everything to its left.
E.g.
# match (1, (2, 3)) with (a, (b, c) as d) -> d;;
- : int * (int * int) = (1, (2, 3))

As compared to using parentheses to disambiguate and specifically limit what as is binding.
# match (1, (2, 3)) with (a, ((b, c) as d)) -> d;;
- : int * int = (2, 3)

Secondly, a set of arguments to a constructor is not a tuple, unless we explicitly make it one. A side note here that while using a constructor looks like a function application, it is not.
Your FromInt constructor does not take one argument which is a tuple of values, but rather two arguments. The fact that it looks like it's taking a single tuple argument is a side-effect of OCaml syntax.
As dogbert notes, you can explicitly make it take a single tuple by using parentheses when defining the constructor. At this point the constructor takes one argument which happens to be a tuple containing multiple values.

Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I cannot change the constructor of FromInt. I'm trying to solve a recurring pattern where I have a visitor for a type which has a lot of constructors, and a function handling each constructor. And I would like to avoid repeating the arguments from the constructor to the handling function.

There may be come ppx wizardry to solve this, but nothing I know of in the core language.

You currently have two separate values in the FromInt constructor. If you can't change the definition, you'll need to wrap a and b in a tuple yourself before calling sum_pair:
| FromInt (a, b) -> sum_pair (a, b)

Playground

Another option is to store a tuple in FromInt (note the parentheses):
type foo_t =
  | FromInt of (int * int)
  | FromFloat of float

With this, you can call sum_pair directly:
| FromInt pair -> sum_pair pair

Playground

Thank you. Ideally, I would like to avoid your first suggestion as I don't want to retype everything. The second suggestion doesn't work either as I cannot change the foo_t type.

This is not possible as far as I know. Depending on how much you are ready to refactor the existing code, one way to implement a visitor pattern is to extract the signature of each visitor as its own type.
Let's say that all your visitor may return this common result type:
type res = I of int | F of float

Then, you define each possible visitor argument type, and the visitor function that uses that argument (in practice you would interface with visitors using a module):
type a = int * int
let visit_a (x, y) =
  I (x + y)

type b = float
let visit_b u =
  F (u *. 2.)

type c = int * float
let visit_c (x, u) =
  I (x * (Int.of_float u))

Each possible set of function argument is grouped in a type:
type abc =
  | A of a
  | B of b
  | C of c

You can also imagine a variant D of a, there is not necessarily a one-to-one relationship here.
And your dispatching function doesn't need to destructure each type individually, it only knows that there are aguments to be passed down to functions:
let dispatch = function
  | A x -> visit_a x
  | B x -> visit_b x
  | C x -> visit_c x

For example:
# [dispatch (A (5,6));
   dispatch (B 1.5);
   dispatch (C (3, 9.5))];;

- : res list = [I 11; F 3.; I 27]

This is similar to what other answers said, but I think an example is a bit more useful to show how to decouple the individual types from the variant.
